# Pegando primeira e última data do mês anterior

Tags: java, eclipse, data, selenium-webdriver

Estou utilizando no Eclipse o Selenium, para automatização de envio de comandos pra um site, através de arquivos JAVA. Nesse site, preciso fazer uma consulta de datas. Eu fiz assim pra testar:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.name("form:dtEmissao_input"));
element.sendKeys("01/04/2016");
element = driver.findElement(By.name("form:emissFim_input"));
element.sendKeys("12/04/2016");
```

Contudo, eu queria que ele sempre pegue o primeiro e o último dia do mês anterior. Como eu posso fazer isso? Precisa importar alguma biblioteca no meu arquivo JAVA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa de nenhuma biblioteca externa! Aqui está uma possível solução

```
public static voi main(String[] args){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    d = c.getTime();

    //subtrai 1 do mês atual para pegar o anterior
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

    //seta primeiro dia do mês
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    d = c.getTime();
    System.out.println("Data do primeiro dia do mes passado: " + sdf.format(d));
    //seta ultimo dia do mês
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    d = c.getTime();
    System.out.println("Data do ultimo dia do mes passado: " + sdf.format(d));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Usando Java 8

Em Java 8 isso é trivial, pois faz parte da API.

```
LocalDateTime data = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime ultimoDiaDoMesAnterior = data.minusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
System.out.println(ultimoDiaDoMesAnterior.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
```

Note que `LocalDateTime` não considera fuso-horário, portanto é mais seguro do que usar `Date` ou `Calendar`.

## Java <= 7

### Usando a biblioteca JodaTime

Solução muito simples:

```
LocalDate ultimoDiaDoMesAnterior = date..minusMonths(1).dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
```

**Esta é a forma recomendada para versões do Java menores ou iguais à 7.**

### Usando `java.util.Calendar`

Com a API antiga costuma-se executar a operação de, pelo menos, duas formas.

A primeira é usando `Calendar` para subtrair um mês e recuperar o último dia daquele mês, assim:

```
Date data = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(data);
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(c.getTime()));
```

A segunda é usando `Calendar` para definir o primeiro dia do mês atual, depois subtrair um dia para chegar ao final do mês anterior, assim:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(c.getTime()));
```

Mas cuidado com `Calendar` porque você pode facilmente incorrer em problemas com fuso. Confuso?

### Perigos de manipular datas

Não é raro datas digitadas pelo usuário acabarem com valores errados manipuladas. O exemplo mais clássico disso ocorre devido ao horário de verão.

Imagine que a sua JVM está com o seguinte padrão:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

O usuário digitou a data `01/03/2016`, representada pela linha abaixo:

```
Date entrada = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/03/2016");
```

Não é incomum que bibliotecas usem manipulação de datas especificando uma zona específica, assim:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
calendar.setTime(entrada);
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(calendar.getTime()));
```

O problema nesse caso é que ele não sabe que `entrada` foi criada com uma timezone diferente do que está sendo usado na manipulação com `Calendar`.

Então, ao contrário do que se esperava, `01/02/2016 00:00:00`, o resultado é `29/01/2016 23:00:00`. Uma hora "roubada" pelo horário de verão.

Como `Date` não armazena o fuso horário, não tem como saber com qual fuso ele foi criado e isso pode gerar problemas com diversos frameworks, ainda mais em sistemas web. Alguns frameworks podem assumir uma zona fixa padrão, outros podem assumir a zona de acordo com as informações do cabeçalho HTTP de localidade providas pelo navegador.

Enfim, a única forma segura de usar `Calendar` e `Date` é que todas as rotinas que façam isso especifiquem o mesmo `Timezone` e o mesmo `Locale` em todas as operações. As bibliotecas e frameworks devem todos receber a configuração para manter o padrão.

No caso de um sistema web com suporte à localização já é bem mais complicado, pois cada usuário pode estar numa zona diferente. A solução pode ser converter tudo para `GMT` ou colocar passar a zona do usuário para todas as rotinas que vão manipular datas.